# How to count and print out the number of buttons clicked in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I need a function to count how many buttons were clicked in a group of maybe three of four  buttons. That is if I click on two buttons out of the three or four buttons, it should print out you clicked two buttons

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import Floatlayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.label import Label 

class LandingScreen(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LandingScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

  # put whatever pos_hint value you want and the on_press event.           
self.btn1=Button(text='button1 ', size_hint=(0.5, 0.5)))
self.btn2=Button(text='button1 ', size_hint=(0.5, 0.5)))
self.btn3=Button(text='button1 ', size_hint=(0.5, 0.5)))


            
self.add_widget(self.btn1)
self.add_widget(self.btn2)
self.add_widget(self.btn3)

 
 # I need a function to count the numbers of buttons clicked out of the three buttons         

class SplashApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return LandingScreen()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    SplashApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

When the button gets pressed, it should trigger a function. This function should add a unique ID to a set. This unique ID can be 1 for the first button, 2 for the second, etc.

It might look like this:

```
mySet = set()
def onClick(self, id):
    mySet.add(id)
#bind the function to the button
self.btn1.bind(on_press = self.onClick(1))
self.btn2.bind(on_press = self.onClick(2))
self.btn3.bind(on_press = self.onClick(3))
```

To get how many buttons were pressed, you can then just get the length by doing `len(mySet)`.

**Why use a set over a list?**

A list can have multiple of the same item. A set must be unique. If a uesr clicks the button 2 times, the list could look like this: [1, 2, 2]. A set, despite how many clicks, will look like this: [1, 2]

Comment: What if I am using different function for the on_press event

Comment: @Thompson then just add the `mySet` variable globally and add `mySet.add(Id)` somewhere in the function.

Comment: After adding the code I got an AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'add'

Comment: Am still open to more contributions

Comment: @Thompson my bad. I declared the set wrong. I edited the post. Instead of `mySet = {}` it should be `mySet = set()`

Comment: @NumberC is there any perticular reason why you chose to use `set` instead of a simple `list`?

Comment: A list can have multiple of the same item. A set must be unique. If a uesr clicks the button 2 times, the list could look like this: [1, 2, 2]. A set, despite how many clicks, will look like this: [1, 2].

Comment: @NumberC can you please help me put it inside the code I posted and setting different function name for the  on_press event of the three buttons. Cause am getting some errors here due to other codes I have under those functions. I would really appreciate it

Comment: The thing is when the  buttons are  pressed they  are supposed to change their  background color and  print how many of the buttons are pressed. When I add the code you gave me earlier to each of the buttons function, I got an error that the button is not define in the landingScreen class

Comment: @Thompson make sure everything is indented to be inside the class. At this point, this is an entirely different issue than the question.